# Why say x = x in Python?

Tags: python, identity, equals

In [this file](http://matplotlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/matplotlib/trunk/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py?revision=6648&view=markup&pathrev=6648), in the function `cross_from_below(x, threshold)`, there is a line that says `threshold = threshold`.  What's the point of this line?  Does this do something differently than if this command weren't there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no point to that assignment.  It's probably just left over and should be removed.  The next function is nearly identical, and doesn't have it.

Comment: Esp since the function cross_from_above, right below it, follows a similar pattern but does not have the threshold = threshold assignment.

Answer (score 8):

No, in the specific example you quote, that line is (harmless but) redundant -- indeed the very next function (cross threshold from above rather than from below) is almost identical (save of course for the direction of the comparisons), lacks that extra assignment, yet works just the same way.

The one and only case where something like `threshold=threshold` would make a difference is in a `def` statement, where it's the idiom to force early binding of a name (it makes use of the fact that default values are evaluated at `def` time, i.e., "early";-).  But that's not what that code is doing -- just adding it for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

It could mean something. For example, if `threshold` was a property of a class, then assigning it could call a setter method.

But in this case, I think it's a typo. I've looked at the [changelog](http://matplotlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/matplotlib/trunk/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py?view=diff&pathrev=6648&r1=6647&r2=6648) and there is no hint that this was intentional for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Or it could be one of those cases where it made sense at some point to write something like :

```
 self.threshold = threshold
```

because the function was a method of some class that needed to kept the threshold. (In which case, it would mean something else, wouldn't it ?)

Comment: which is what aaron just said. Sorry.